# Why is setting the DataContext on a TabControl slower after the first time?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, datacontext

I have a TabControl with multiple TabItems that are displaying different aspects of a Person object. I am setting the DataContext of the TabControl to the Person object in code-behind. The first time I do this, it takes about 2-3 seconds for the information to be displayed. After the first time, selecting a different Person record and setting the DataContext takes about 25 seconds. Any ideas why it takes so long the second, and subsequent times, and how to fix this?

Xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl">
    <TabItem>
        <...controls databound to various properties of a Person object...>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
Person person = SelectedPerson;
MyTabControl.DataContext = person;
```

Comment: Does it take longer with each selection? Or does every subsequent selection take roughly the same time to load?

Comment: Every subsequent selection takes about the same amount of time, around 25 seconds. Re-selecting the initial record loaded, which took 2-3 seconds the first time, will now take about 25 seconds.

Comment: Can you show a simplified version of your code that demonstrates the same problem?

Comment: Do you use any `ValidationRule`s in your bindings?

Comment: Just a guess, but every time you unset the `DataContext` then the bound items are probably being cleaned up somehow, in addition to being recreated when the new `DataContext` is set.  Of course, the first time you do this, there is no cleanup required and this would be faster than subsequent runs.